# How do I remove a field from Typescript type with [key: string]: any

Tags: typescript

I have a type definition from an npm module and want to remove param1 or make it optional

```
type A = {
    [key: string]: any,
    param1: string
    param2: string
}
```

I tried Omit function suggested by Typescript but didn't work well

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type B = Omit<A,"param1">
// expect: B = {[key:string]: any, param2: string}
// actual: B = {[key:string]: any}
```

I'm using typescript 2.8.3. How can I get my expected result?

UPDATE:
I did more dig around and found following.

```
// this copies index and extra type correctly
type B = {
  [P in keyof A]: A[P];
}

// this only copies index type
type C = keyof A
type B = {
  [P in C]: A[P];
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Since the type has an index signature `keyof A` will always be string. Basically the index eats up all the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Mapped types that rely on `keyof` like `Exclude` won't work properly here because index signature absorbs other properties. `keyof A` is a union of properties, i.e. `string`.

A problem could likely be addressed in the opposite way, by adding `?` modifiers to existing keys and removing them for some properties:

```
type B = Partial<A> & { param1: A['param1'] };
```

Since this will become cumbersome for multiple properties, the type possibly has to be duplicated and modified.

Comment: Thanks. But my `type A` actually is a property for a React dropdown and has more than 20 parameters so this approach is practical in that scenario.

Comment: So you need to have 1 prop changed and 19 unchanged? I guess copying and pasting it is the way this should be done for now. I would like to know if there is a better way to do that, but it seems that currently there's none. If this was your own type, it would be reasonable to keep index type and the rest in 2 different types to make `Omit` work.

Comment: It is coming from npm package so I don't have control over it